# Buttons generated in for loop are not getting correct values

Tags: jquery, html, loops, button, for-loop

I have a dynamic webpage that displays a list of results, with multiple pages. I currently have functional "previous page" and "next page" buttons, but I want to add specific page buttons like many websites have, so that you can go to a page number directly rather than scrolling through the pages one at a time. To do this I am using a for loop to generate the page buttons, since the number of pages is variable. Here is my code:

```
@{ var val = 1;}
@for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++)
{
    <text> @val </text>
    <button type="submit" class="page-button" value="@val"> @i </button>
    val++;
}
```

The buttons are being generated, except all of them are getting a value of 1. This is how I'm testing what the buttons values are:

```
$(".page-button").on("click", function(event) {
    alert($(".page-button").val());
});
```

Every button pops up an alert that says "1" when it is clicked, even though @val is being incremented correctly (I can tell because  @val  displays the same number as the page button it is next to).

I also tried

```
<button type="submit" class="page-button" value="@i"> @i </button>
```

But again, even though the numbers displayed on the buttons were correct, when I clicked them they all had a value of 1. Why aren't the values being assigned correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know JQuery, but I presume that `$(".page-button").val()` fetches all elements in the document with `class="page-button"` and returns the value of **the first one**. You need to obtain a reference to **the current element** which fired the event.

This seems to work for me:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

but **I really don't know what I'm doing** here.